# How to exit a NodeJs lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that redirects the user to a certain url is a condition is met. Otherwise it should do nothing.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
                 
    if ( a certain condition is met) {
        const response = {
                    status: '302',
                    statusDescription: 'Found',
                    headers: {location: 
                                  [
                                    {
                                      key: 'Location',
                                      value: 'https://www.yahoo.fr',
                                      
                                    }
                                  ],
                            },
                    };
        
        return response;
    
    }
    else {
        // continue with the request
    }
};
```

The lambda function is behind a CloudFront distribution and handles the viewer requests.

When the condition is not met I need the lambda function to send the request to the CloudFront distribution without changing anything.

How can I complete this function such that it continues with the original request?

Comment: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-redirect-url.html) I hope this one helps you

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';
    
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  if (a certain condition is met) {
    const response = {
      status: '302',
      statusDescription: 'Found',
      headers: {
        location: [{
          key: 'Location',
          value: 'https://www.yahoo.fr',                       
        }],
      },
    };
            
    callback(null, response);
  }
  callback(null, request);
};
```

Comment: it would be better to explain what the code is doing so that its better to understand for the OP